# How can i close a text document that was being written to

Tags: vb.net

this is the error Message I get when running this script. It is part of a function that emails off the txt file. Can anyone help?

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Keys\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Dim filePath As String = String.Format("C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Keys\log.txt")

        Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(filePath)

        Using writer As New StreamWriter(filePath, True)
            If Not fileExists Then
                writer.WriteLine("Start Error Log for today")
            End If
            writer.WriteLine(RichTextBox1.Text)
            RichTextBox1.Text = ("")
            writer.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure the file isn't already open?  what happens if you try to open in in Windows Explorer?

Comment: the file is open from writing to it with the program

Comment: Not related to the issue, but you don't need to call `writer.Close()` when you have a `Using/End Using` block.

Comment: Related to the issue, see this: https://serverfault.com/a/1980

Comment: It isn't related to that as i know what is keeping it open i just want to close the file its self not anything else

Comment: `the file is open from writing to it with the program` with a different program? Or another thread within your program? You can have it open in Notepad but not Excel for instance, but write to it from .Net at the same time. What has it open?

Comment: That part of the program is the only section that is using the text document and when it goes to iterate and perform the action again as the timer will then count back down it comes up with that error message as i cant seem to close the text document before the next iteration

Comment: I wouldn't say that that automatically makes the problem reside in this code or even this program. `End Using` or `writer.Close()/Dispose()` _**will**_ close the file. -- What interval have you set on the timer?